# Create View table basing column in other table rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a View table in SQL Server out of regular table where I need to add an extra column  **PURCHASE DATE (X)**. This will be the outcome and the regular table it's the same just without the Column X.

`+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| ID |    Item     | Quantity | Price  |   Date    |  Category  | PURCHASE DATE (X) |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| 12 | BOND A 5%   |       40 | $1.25  | 2/20/2012 | BUY        |                   |
| 11 | BOND A 5%   |       40 | $1.25  | 5/1/2013  | INT INCOME |                   |
| 10 | BOND A 5%   |       40 | $1.25  | 9/23/2013 | SELL       |                   |
|  9 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | $3     | 6/30/2015 | BUY        |                   |
|  8 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | 0.05   | 2/1/2016  | INT INCOME |                   |
|  7 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | 0.05   | 2/1/2017  | INT INCOME |                   |
|  6 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | 0.05   | 2/1/2018  | INT INCOME |                   |
|  5 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | $5     | 6/30/2018 | SELL       |                   |
|  4 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 8/24/2013 | BUY        |                   |
|  3 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 3/1/2014  | INT INCOME |                   |
|  2 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 3/2/2015  | INT INCOME |                   |
|  1 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 3/31/2018 | SELL       |                   |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+`

How can I make the `PURCHASE DATE (X)` column equal the `Date` column for the most recent `BUY` row with a matching `Item` value (based on `Date` rather than `ID`)?

Expected result:

`+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| ID |    Item     | Quantity | Price  |   Date    |  Category  | PURCHASE DATE (X) |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+
| 12 | BOND A 5%   |       40 | $1.25  | 2/20/2012 | BUY        | 2/20/2012         |
| 11 | BOND A 5%   |       40 | $1.25  | 5/1/2013  | INT INCOME | 2/20/2012         |
| 10 | BOND A 5%   |       40 | $1.25  | 9/23/2013 | SELL       | 2/20/2012         |
|  9 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | $3     | 6/30/2015 | BUY        | 6/30/2015         |
|  8 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | 0.05   | 2/1/2016  | INT INCOME | 6/30/2015         |
|  7 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | 0.05   | 2/1/2017  | INT INCOME | 6/30/2015         |
|  6 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | 0.05   | 2/1/2018  | INT INCOME | 6/30/2015         |
|  5 | BOND A 5%   |      100 | $5     | 6/30/2018 | SELL       | 6/30/2015         |
|  4 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 8/24/2013 | BUY        | 8/24/2013         |
|  3 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 3/1/2014  | INT INCOME | 8/24/2013         |
|  2 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 3/2/2015  | INT INCOME | 8/24/2013         |
|  1 | BOND B 7.5% |      500 | $10    | 3/31/2018 | SELL       | 8/24/2013         |
+----+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+------------+-------------------+`

Comment: Skip the view, add a _computed column_ to your table.

Comment: That's a really good approach @jarlh but I need it to be a View since we already it. I'm just adding this column to the View. To make easier I skipped that.

Comment: And yes there will be other type of items. That's why we need to based our query in the row Item to pull the BUY from table.

Comment: Done, I also modified the tables to hace more than one item since this is going to be the case. The answered provided by @Gordonlinoff

Answer (score 1):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

Is this what you want?

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*,
           (case when item = 'Bond A 5%' then '2015-06-30' end) as [PURCHASE DATE (X)]
    from t;
```

Comment: This seems to be a very strange use-case ... Maybe OP can clarify further?

Comment: What if instead of hard pasting 'Bond A 5%'  I need whatever Item is in that row?

Comment: @AlexMartinez . . . This answers the original version of the question.  You can look in the edit history.

Comment: Maybe I was missing that part @GordonLinoff . We need to based out query on the Item name for that row and not a hard pasted value.

Answer (score 0):

So, this was pretty much what I did to solve the issue in case in can help someone:

```
create view A_T as
select A.*,
       (SELECT TOP 1 T.Date FROM MainTable T WHERE T.Item=A.Item AND T.Client=A.Client AND Category='BUY' ORDER BY 1 DESC) AS [PURCHASE DATE (X)]
from MainTable A;
```

Hope that helps